# Foreign key on identifying relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

Let's start by a quick definition of an identifying relationship that I found on the web :

*An identifying relationship is when the existence of a row in a child table depends on a row in a parent table, this means the primary key of a child table contains a column that belongs to a foreign key referencing a parent table.*

My example: I use SQL Server and my example is the following :

1. I created a data table to store data about schemas (metadata), and yes, sys views information are not enough in case you are wondering :)

   My metadata table is called `Schemas_Metadata` and has a `Name` column as the  primary key.

   ```
   Schemas_Metadata
   ----------------
   PK (Name)
   ```
2. I created another metadata table to store data about tables and my metadata table is called `Tables_Metadata` and has a `Name` column and a `Schema_Name` column (foreign key referencing the `Name` column in the `Schemas_Metadata` table) and a composed primary key (`Schema_Name, Name`). This is an identifying relationship.

   ```
   Tables_Metadata
   PK (Schema_Name, Name)
   ```
3. I created another metadata table to store data about columns called `Columns_Metadata` and it too has a `Name` column, a `Table_Name` column and unfortunately a `Schema_Name` column (`Table_Name, Schema_Name` are a foreign key referencing the `Schema_Name,Name` columns in the `Tables_Metadata` table) and a composed primary key of (`Schema_Name, Table_Name, Name`). This also is an identifying relationship.

   ```
   Columns_Metadata
   PK (Schema_Name, Table_Name, Name)
   ```

My question:

At the third level, do I need to create two columns `Schema_Name` and `Table_Name` in `Columns_Metadata` table and do I have to create columns I don't need each time I create a foreign key on an identifying relationship, or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: If you have a foreign key, you have all you need to link the tables with a select statement, you don't need to replicate any other column that already exists in parent table

Comment: The best way is to not try to do this yourself. This information is ALL readily available and 100% realtime right now. You can add any additional information to any object anywhere in the system through extended properties.

Comment: Your definition of an identifying relationship is backwards. An existence dependency doesn't imply an FK in a PK; rather, non-nullable FKs imply an existence dependency, whether they're in the PK or not. Identifying relationships are about PKs containing FKs: given a PK `(a, b)` in which `a` identifies entity set `A` and `(a, b)` identifies entity set `B`, we can rewrite it as `(a, (a, b))` which identifies the relationship `(A, B)`. Thus `B`'s identity depends on its relationship with `A`, and `B`'s relationship with `A` is inherent in its identity.

Comment: I would have to disagree partially with that, non-nullable FK imply an existence dependency (that is correct), but it is not considered an identifying relationship if the FK is not a part of the PK.

Comment: I didn't say FK outside of PK is an identifying relationship, I specifically said identifying relationships are about PKs containing FKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me express my opinion that the already existent design of the information schema and the sys schema are very elaborate, in-depth and intricate compared to your question which, if we forget for a moment that its CONTENT concerns metadata, is a very simple case of table design. Thus, I doubt you need to make another schema.

To answer your question: I would create an id column on Tables_Metadata, put the PK on id alone, and add a check constraint unique (schema_name,name).

Then, The Columns_Metadata table need only have two fields: Name, and Tables_Metadata_id FK to  Tables_Metadata.id

Comment: Especially since you can add extended properties to your tables, schemas and columns. For example, see https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+extended+properties

Comment: This is a good alternative for creating tables to store metadata but i dont like the fact that the 'value' column of the 'sys.extended_properties' view has a 'sql_variant' type (i have less control on the data....)